# How to add handler to \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output

Tags: magento2, helper

I'd like to display the unit of measurement after each product attribute with some dimension (mm, g, …).

To prevent duplicated code in each PHTML template file that probably displays a product with attributes, I thought it might be a good idea, to add a handler to the output helper, which could append those units.

For example `attributes.phtml` uses `<?= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>` to output the attributes value. I guess the sense behind using `$_helper->productAttribute` instead of simply outputting `$_data['value']`, is that the value might be translated to another format or something similar.

From the code in the `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output`-helper, I figured out, that one might add handlers to the output helper. But I couldn't find any documentation on how to do so or where to add such a handler.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing, found this issue on magento github :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12371

In the thread, found this work around:
https://gist.github.com/quisse/b78ee3d121a4c9b8dd141334c8fa27a8

There also a PR https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14527, which would permit a more elegant solution : https://gist.github.com/quisse/10e2a5a90f8dc55f82f972efe138e3ad, but it seems it haven't been merge